# how to select any 2 or more variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a question to create a new variable.I have several variables named A,B,C,D,E,F,G.All variables are 0/1 binary variable.So I want to create a new variable which shows any 3 or more those variables equal to 1.

For example,

```
new_variable =0;
if ANY 3 or more variables(A,B,C,D,E,F,G) =1 then new_variable =1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's <strike>no way</strike> sort of a way to do the syntax like you have, but since you're smart and have 0/1 binaries, there's a very easy way if you think about it a sec, to see if 3 or more are 1.

```
if sum(of a b c d e f g) >= 3 then new_Variable=1;
```

Actually a bit simpler:

```
new_Variable = (sum(of a b c d e f g) GE 3);
```

as true=1 false=0 when you evaluate a boolean expression.

If your data are in an array or with a common prefix, there is a way to do that more easily:

```
new_variable = (sum(of arrayname[*]) GE 3);
```

or

```
new_variable = (sum(of varprefix:) GE 3);
```

where `arrayname` is your array or `varprefix` is the common prefix your variables (and only your variables) share.

---

Edit: There is, sort of, a way to do this in a similar kind of syntax.  Using `countc`:

```
data have;
 call streaminit(7);
 array vars[7] a b c d e f g;
 do _n_ = 1 to 20;
   do _i = 1 to dim(vars);
     vars[_i] = rand('Binomial',.2,1);
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  if countc(cats(of a--g),'1') ge 3;
run;
```

If you had something other than 1/0, you could use `catx` to delimit them with a space or something, and then `countw` to look for the complete value; here, `11` will look like two `1`s not eleven, if that were possible in the data.

There are a lot of other solutions, by the way; maybe some others will come and mention them.  `CALL SORTN` and then look for the first instance of 1, for example.